# How do I use wcscpy_s in XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode

Anyone have suggestions on how to convert the following to compile in latest version of XCode? XCode reccomends converting `wcspy_s` to `wcspy`, but I've read that these aren't the same methods. I tried it and then I get more errors.

```
if (name) wcscpy_s<sizeof(dinfo.name)/sizeof(pxcCHAR)>(dinfo.name,name);
if (did) wcscpy_s<sizeof(dinfo.did)/sizeof(pxcCHAR)>(dinfo.did,did);
```

Here's my project: https://github.com/robksawyer/ofxRSSDKv2 and if you're curious https://github.com/robksawyer/RealsenseOFPointcloud

Comment: the _s variant is a non-standard (or sort of standard but oft-ignored) Microsoft secure version. They don't behave the same and are called differently. Here is some documentation on the differences: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcscpy . I'm not going to get into the politics of this mess other than to say it annoys me.

Comment: Is it ok to just use wcscpy then?

Comment: You should be using `wcslcpy` as the replacement.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm receiving the following error. Any ideas? `Comparison between pointer and integer`

Comment: `if (name) wcslcpy<sizeof(mdesc.friendlyName)/sizeof(pxcCHAR)>(mdesc.friendlyName, name);` is throwing the error `Comparison between pointer and integer ('size_t (*)(wchar_t *, const wchar_t *, size_t)' and 'unsigned long')`

Comment: `wcslcpy` takes three params (source, destination, length) and I don't think it's templated. Not sure if it's standard, either. [`wcsncpy` is.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcsncpy)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the above to the following worked. Thanks @user3386109 and @user4581301.

```
if (name) wcslcpy(dinfo.name,name,sizeof(dinfo.name)/sizeof(pxcCHAR));
if (did) wcslcpy(dinfo.did,did,sizeof(dinfo.did)/sizeof(pxcCHAR));
```